# Redirect a WordPress Multisite url after it has been change to a new one

Tags: multisite, redirect

In the multisite dashboard network admin, you can edit a site and change its url.

For example, I have this url: multisite.com/old and I have change it to multisite.com/new

How can I make the multisite.com/old redirect to multisite.com/new so that users will not get lost and will not return an error? Current error is "Page not found / File not found".

I have tried adding this to my htaccess with no success

```
RewriteRule ^old/(.*)$ /new/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

And also this one

```
Redirect 301 /old/ https://www.multisite.com/new/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I just had to remove the dash on the redirect code since I'm typing multisite.com/old without the last dash

```
Redirect 301 /old/ https://www.multsite.com/new/
Redirect 301 /old https://www.multsite.com/new/
```